# Is my understanding of this theorem on the limit of a sequence correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to know if I understood the theorem I need to use on this exercise correctly, so let me tell the theorem and then the problem.

$Theorem$:

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$ and $f$ is continuous in $L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(L)$.

So the theorem states that, provided the sequence $a_n$ approaches a number $L$ when $n$ goes to infinity, then I can take any function $f$ that's continuous on $L$ and know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)$ will be the same than$f(L$).

$Exercise$

Let $a_n=\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Of course I could solve this by determining that $\frac{\pi}{n}\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})=\sin(0)=0$.

But using the theorem I could also take some function that's continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, for example $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Now evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(0)=0.$

The information this would give me is that, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(L)$, $f(L)=0$. This means $\sin(L)=0$.

Solving $\sin(L)=0$ I get $L=0$.

So after all, the ultimate "goal" of this theorem seems to be to provide us with this last equation we can solve for $L$, but it feels a bit redundant since, in order to get this equation, I have to solve the limit of the sequence first (so I already now $L$)! I get the feeling that I'm overcomplicating it. Is this a right understanding and approach to the theorem?

Comment: "Of course I could solve this by determining that πn→0 when n→∞, so that limn→∞sin(πn)=sin(0)=0"  But you *can't* state that without knowing the theorem first.

Comment: Yes, now I understood it and I see how I complicated everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> Of course I could solve this by determining that $\frac{\pi}{n}\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}sin(\frac{\pi}{n})=sin(0)=0$.

In solving it this way you *are* using the theorem. $a_n=\frac\pi n$, and $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. The theorem guarantees that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)
&=\sin(L)\\
&=\sin(0)\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Of course, I see it now. How silly of me. I overcomplicated everything. Thanks Robjohn.

Comment: The tricky part with limits is to know when you can pass them across functions, integrals, infinite sums, etc. This theorem tells one case where you to pass a limit inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

> Of course I could solve this by determining that $\frac πn→0$ when $n→∞$, so that $\lim_{n→∞}\sin(\frac πn)=\sin(0)=0$

Not if you don't know the theorem in the first place, you can't!

You are *ASSUMING* that $\lim_{n\to a} f(a_n)=f(\lim_{n \to a} a_n)$.  Why are you assuming that?

Consider $f(x) = \lceil x \rceil $ (the next integer equal or more than $x$) so that $f(0) = 0$ but $f(\frac 1n) = 1$ for every $n$.

Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}  f(\frac 1n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lceil \frac 1n \rceil=\lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1$.

So your argument that $\frac 1n \to 0$ means $f(\frac 1n) \to f(0)=0$ doesn't hold.

You can *NOT* assume that.

The theorem is saying nothing more or less than you *are* allowed to assume that if $f$ is continuous.

($\lceil x \rceil$ is not continuous.)

> So after all, the ultimate "goal" of this theorem seems to be to provide us with this last equation we can solve for L, but it feels a bit redundant since, in order to get this equation, I have to solve the limit of the sequence first (so I already now L)!

Yes.  You know $a_n \to L$ and you know $f(L)$.  But you don't know what $f(a_n)\to ????$ is.  The theorem is utterly essential to know that if $a_n \to L$ then we know that $f(a_n) \to f(L)$ (if $f$ is continuous).

No redundancy.  Pure essentiality.

I think your issue is that you were taking the theorem for granted but not realizing it.

Comment: That was my issue in deed. Thanks for the explanations. I see my mistake now.

Comment: +1 for last paragraph for figuring out the issue of asker. Most students assume too much without bothering to think if their assumptions are justified.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the theorem is to exchange limits and continuous functions.  Under the theorem's hypotheses,
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(a_n) = f \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \right)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Thanks for answering. So the theorem is not useful to find $L$, only to state that the limit of a function evaluated on a sequence is the function evaluated on the limit of the sequence? How could this be useful in order to solve an excercise such as the one I was given?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin(\pi/n) = \sin \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \pi/n \right)$.  The limit on the right-hand side is elementary.

Answer (score 0):

The utility of the theorem in this exercise is to allow you to use

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}=0$

in order to infer that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})=\sin(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{n})=0$.

Note that as $a_n = \sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$, L actually refers to the limit of this sequence, so by writing $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(L)$ you are actually writing $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}))=f(L)$,

Also note that you cannot infer L = 0 from $\sin(L) = 0$